# IE8 fixed position top & bottom resize bug

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, css-position

Based on my CSS, all Browsers including IE7 show my bottom bar correct and fixed, all the time.

```
.bottom-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -235px;
    min-width: 1160px;
    max-width: 130em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However there is something strange in IE8. If you resize the browser window height with help of your right corner at the bottom (the way you can change a windows width and height at the same time), all is fine.

But if you resize the window height grapping the top or bottom of your browser window, the bar/div stuck at the position like it would when position was absolute instead of position: fixed.

Any idea how to fix that?

*(Using Doctype for HTML5)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't fix that with the parent float solution from this [thread Umer mentioned](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?658794-IE8-amp-Opera-Fixed-Position-Bug).

So I fixed it with a simple Javascript script which applies position: fixed all the time when the window gets resized.

**HTML**

```
<!--[if IE 8 ]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function () {
            ApplyPositionFixed();
        });
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

**Javascript**

```
function ApplyPositionFixed() {
    // Check if element exists
    if ($("#bottom-bar-content").length) {
        $(".bottom-fixed").attr('style', 'position: fixed;');
        console.log("Window resized");
    }
    else {
        console.info("No element changes on Window resize");
    }
}
```

However. I'm ready for better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution: setting `height` explicitly on the parent element. For example `height: 1%` or `height: 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but the fix in my case was that the parent had `position: relative`. Once I removed that, this issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

for fixed position in IE 8 - ,
**DOCTYPE** is very very important.

one of:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

And its very very important that
those be in first line.

Comment: well, as written, I've used HTML5 doctype. So that seems not the case.